# Can I use Sklearn EllipticEnvelope for univariate data?

Tags: scikit-learn

Sklearn EllipticEnvelope calculates the covariance between two or more features and estimates the outliers. Instead of using two features, I created one new feature by dividing first with the second. When I apply EllipticEnvelope on just this one new feature. It works well. But my question is this a correct way to do it since the model relies on the covariance of two or more features?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It works for both univariate and multivariate. But still would love to see more answers about how it works with a single feature.

“EllipticEnvelope is a function that tries to figure out the key parameters of your data's general distribution by assuming that your entire data is an expression of an underlying multivariate Gaussian distribution. That's an assumption that cannot hold true for all datasets, yet when it does, it proves an effective method indeed for spotting outliers. Simplifying the complex estimations working behind the algorithm as much as possible, we can say that it checks the distance of each observation with respect to a grand mean that takes into account all the variables in your dataset. For this reason, it is able to spot both univariate and multivariate outliers.”

Source: Alberto Boschetti. “Python Data Science Essentials.”.